# How can I sort this array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have an array, `headlines`, that holds several sentences, so like:

```
headlines = ["I see a tree", "Facebook is slow", "plants need water to grow", "There's an orange", "I think we'll agree"] 
first = headlines[0]
second = headlines[1]
third = headlines[2]
```

I am using the [`ruby_rhymes`](https://github.com/vshulman/RubyRhymes) gem which provides a method `#to_phrase.rhymes` which prints out rhyming words for the last word in a string you provide it with. Now to check if the array strings rhyme, I do something like:

```
> first.to_phrase.rhymes.flatten.join(", ").include?(second.to_phrase.rhymes.flatten.join(", "))
=> false
> second.to_phrase.rhymes.flatten.join(", ").include?(third.to_phrase.rhymes.flatten.join(", "))
=> true
```

I want to save these to a text file so I want to sort them in the array so that rhyming pairs are subsequent to one another. I know to sort so that strings follow if the last 3 characters are the same is:

```
headlines.sort! {|a,b|  a[-3,3] <=> b[-3,3] }
```

But I don't know how to do want I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figured it out:

```
headlines.sort_by! { |h| h.to_phrase.rhyme_key }
```

This doesn't work 100% but that's the fault of the dictionary the gem relies on.

Answer (score 0):

By investigating the output of your suggestion you can see that you are on the right track:

```
p headlines.sort {|a,b|  a[-3,3] <=> b[-3,3] }
# => ["Facebook is slow", "There's an orange", "I see a tree", "I think we'll agree", "plants need water to grow"]
```

"...slow" and "...grow" are the only unordered sentences, caused by the letters 'r' and 'o'. A simple hack would be to reverse the order of the comparison like that:

```
p headlines.sort {|a,b|  a[-3,3].reverse <=> b[-3,3].reverse }
# => ["I see a tree", "I think we'll agree", "There's an orange", "Facebook is slow", "plants need water to grow"]
```

Comment: No. This won't work. If the headlines array gets hundreds of strings, your (and my suggested) approach will not work. Nor will it work for words that rhyme but are spelled very differently like `through` and `you`.